# How to pass an ejs variable to javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ejs

I cannot transfer ejs variable to javascript.
I have a for in ejs:

```
<% for(var i=0; i < lyrics.length; i++) {%>
            <!--MELODIE-->

            <br>

            <%= lyrics[i].texte %>
```

and I want to log in browser lyrics[i].texte variable.
I tried `var a = <%= lyrics[i].texte %>;` but it didn't worked. 
I also tried to to set in ejs `<% v1= lyrics[i].texte ; %>` and to set js var equal to v1 but it didn't worked again.
I have to convert lyrics[i].texte into a js variable.

I think that the problems came from .texte after name of var (texte is the name of column in database and it's a string). I store in it a poesy. And when i use a standard var (like <%var = 30%>) it runs ok in js transfer.
Thanks for the help!

Comment: are you sure `lyrics` is an array?

Comment: Hi Nuriddin Kudratov. I'm a beginner in nodejs and I don't know very good how it works but I think that lyrics is close to an array. Lyrics is the return of this: ``` return knex.select('texte').from('lyrics').whereRaw("vers = :versV AND for_id = :for_idV", {
  versV: vers,
  for_idV: for_id
})``` But I surely think that I cannot pass the ejs var to js in basic way and I think thats the problem that I fixed with JSOn.stringify

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<% lyrics.forEach(lyric=> { %>
<li class="<%=lyric.texte %>"><%=lyric.texte %></li>
<% }); %>
```

here is the code for looping `lyrics`, if you want to access a specific `lyric.texte`, you have to make `document.querySelector(".className");` in your javascript file.

Answer (score -1):

First you have to stringify your var because is an array. Use
`var myVar = <%-JSON.stringify(ejsVar)%>;` to fix your problem.

Now you can use myVar in javascript.